# JOGL and just black windows

Tags: java, linux, opengl, ubuntu, jogl

i am working on a project for university, programming in Java.
We are working with **JOGL 2.0 and using OpenGL 2.1** on my system
**Ubuntu 12.10 64bit with Sun Java 6u38**, but when i start
diverse JOGL Application i just get a black window.

The JOGL Libaries are **binded to the project, not to my Java installation.**
I had the same problem with different other Java versions
(Sunjava 6 and 7 and OpenJava 6 and 7).

Under a **MS Windows system** on the same machine everything is working fine.
And when i use the **gdx-Libararies**(which are using OpenGL), everything is working too (on my linux).
On **other linux-machines**, everything is fine too (even with Intel CPU/GPU, other models).

Edit: Other OpenGL application (mesa-utils, games like Team Fortress 2 are working)
A few month ago i used JOGL 1.1.1, installed in my Java Installation for some old code
and it was working fine.

My machine is a Thinkpad L530
Intel Core i3-3110M, 8GB of DDR3
IDE: Netbeans 4.x

So has anybody an idea,**what could be wrong?**

Comment: Do other OpenGL applications (like `glxgears` in `mesa-utils`) work correctly?

Comment: Yes they work. Even bigger application like games (Team Fortress 2) are working. Just my self compiled stuff not.

Comment: Try using GLWindow instead of GLCanvas as seen here https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-2